# Group by one column and sum another column of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have this array

```
[
    2 => [1160, 1155, '06/26/2013', 32.99],
    3 => [1160, 1155, '06/26/2013', 0.00],
    4 => [1160, 1155, '06/24/2013', 20.99],
    5 => [1160, 1155, '06/24/2013', 10.78],
]
```

I want, based on "order_id" array[0] same value, to sum of "amount" array[3].

Comment: Help us to show your tried code of that ..

Comment: Is `foreach()` stops working?? W.Y.T ??

Comment: What is "oder_id"? Where is array[0]?

Comment: order_id is array[0]  and I m looking for some short function like array map ... thanks @swapnesh

Comment: @intekhabkhan I guess its not..you need to loop it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$results = array();

foreach($data as $val){
     if(!array_key_exists($val[0], $results)){
         $results[$val[0]] = 0;
     }
     $results[$val[0]]+= $val[3];
}
```

After this $results will contain the totals keyed off of the order_id

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` like this:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $sum += $row[0];
}
echo $sum; // 4640
```

Comment: This isn't a sum grouped per value of $row[0]...?

Comment: This answer does not satisfy the question requirements.